# On each click event make video play/pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I need to change html5 video tag on each click of li tag

Structure is

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <video>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
      </video>
    </li>
    <li>
      <video>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
      </video>
    </li>
    <li>
      <video>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
      </video>
    </li>
    <li>
      <video>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
      </video>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul id="resultsBox">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

So, the situaltion is that when i click on **One** the first li of video should be start, then when i click on **Two** - then first li of video should be pause or stop and the second li of video should be start and so on...

I tried the jquery like this...

```
jQuery("#resultsBox li").on('click', function (e) {
    jQuery(".flexslider .slides").contents().find("video").get(0).play();
});
```

I plays only first video and not the other videos. Secondly i had tried with the each function,too but not work so far.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues you have is that your callback function (called when the `click` event happens) does not use the information about which video was clicked, it just tried to find the first video and play it.

One way to fix is to listen to clicks on the video element itself and calling "play" on it:

```
jQuery("video").on('click', function (e) {
  this.play();
});
```

If you really need to listen for clicks on the `li` element, then you just need to find the video within (by using `find` on the clicked object) and then calling `play()` on it:

```
jQuery(".flexslider li").on('click', function (e) {
    jQuery(this).find("video")[0].play();
});
```

*Note: I've changed to `.flexslider` because the HTML you sent didn't have anything matching the other selector, but you can update it there if you need.*

Here's a working example in case you want to play around:

https://jsfiddle.net/9s57L492/

Comment: Sir, actually it is working on clicking on individual videos. My scope is that i need to click on "One" and accordingly the video should be played.

Comment: That's what my solution does (test it on the jsfiddle link I've shared), when you click on one of the videos, the video you clicked starts playing. Is it not working correctly (sorry if I'm misunderstanding your issue).

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
jQuery("#resultsBox li").on('click', function (e) {
 let itemIndex = jQuery(this).index();
jQuery(".flexslider li").eq(itemIndex).siblings('li').find('video').pause();

   jQuery(".flexslider li").eq(itemIndex).find("video").play();
});
```

Comment: I need to change video on click of (#resultsBox li) element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <div class="slides">
        <li id="one">
            <video controls>
                <source type="video/mp4" src="########sample.mp4">
            </video>
        </li>
        <li id="two">
            <video controls>
                <source type="video/mp4" src="########sample.mp4">
            </video>
        </li>
        <li id="three">
            <video controls>
                <source type="video/mp4" src="########sample.mp4">
            </video>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="resultsBox">
    <li data-target="one">One</li>
    <li data-target="two">Two</li>
    <li data-target="three">Three</li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".resultsBox li").on("click", function(event){
        var targetId = $(this).data("target");
        var targetElement =  $("#" + target + " video");
        if(!targetElement.paused) {
            $("video")[0].pause()
            targetElement[0].play(); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```